# Error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Invalid WSDL access, no SOAP request expected C#

Tags: c#, soap, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am consuming SOAP web service in my .net core application. I am getting below error in c# code

"The remote server returned an error: (500) Invalid WSDL access, no SOAP request expected."

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" 
xmlns:urn=""urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style""> 
<soap:Header/><soap:Body><urn:Zftm0008><Details></Details> 
<PernrNo>""00192292""</PernrNo></urn:Zftm0008></soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>";
string url = "http://url";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ABC", "@ABC");

        byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
        req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
        Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
```

So after consuming it in .net core application i am getting below error at req.GetRequestStream(); line.

Service is in SAP and I am consuming it in .net

please help me to resolve this issue.

EDIT:

I am able to get response but the response is WSDL of the service but I want result of SOAP in XML.

Comment: You can compare working and non working with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare first request of both and make non working look like working.  Are you on same machine?  I suspect different machines and you may have issue with credentials.  I would use default credentials (uses the current login credentials) instead of username and password.

Comment: actually i am getting WSDL response in req.GetRequestStream().. but i want result XML not WSDL.

Comment: Does webpage support xml?

Comment: yes.. it is. when i pass request using SOAPUI then i am getting response in it but when i pass that soap request in above code then i am getting response as a WSDL not like SOAP result. if @jdweng do not understand then please let me know, i will tell you more in detail

Comment: I understand the issue and seen lots of times before.  There are too many reason for the error.  That is why I suggest that you use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the first request from the SOAPUI with the c#.  Then make the c# look like the SOAPUI.   You are not getting a valid response where the response status is 200 OK.  You are getting an error code 500.

Comment: It is working fine with soapui tool. we are getting response in it. but that request i am passing is not working using above code.

Comment: Use sniffer and compare the headers in first request in working and non work applications.  The default headers in Net library are different from other tools.